# Adjoint, self-adjoint, Which is the proper noun?

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

I'm currently learning linear algebra,
and I was confused by these two terminologies.

It seems that adjoint is the tranpose of cofactor matrix,
and a self-adjoint operator has a matrix representation whose conjugate tranpose equal to itself.

But I just met a question, that ask me to prove

$$(im~L)^\perp=ker~L^*$$

where $L^*$ is the adjiont of L

It indicates that L*, the adjoint of L, is the conjugate transpose of L.

I wonder whether adjoint has something to do with self-adjoint.

If not, then what's their difference, and how do I tell the difference when digesting the description of any other question.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The adjoint $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ of a matrix $A$ such that $\operatorname{adj}(A)A=A\operatorname{adj}(A)=\det(A)I$ is called the *‘classical adjoint’* or *‘adjugate’* of $A$. The adjoint $L^\ast$ such that $\langle Lx,y\rangle=\langle x,L^\ast y\rangle$ is called the *‘Hermitian adjoint’* of $L$. Both classical adjoint and Hermitian adjoint are briefly called ‘adjoint’ in older texts, but in modern textbooks, ‘adjoint’ usually refers to Hermitian adjoint rather than classical adjoint.